# Взаимодействие объектов в заданной предметной области

Tags: java, ооп

Здраствуйте. Мне нужно создать несколько классов и их взаимодействие в такой предметной области:

*Туризм (маршрут, участок, категория участка, поход)*

Туризм - главный класс. Слова в скобочках тоже должны быть классами.

У меня уже есть некоторые наброски, но я не уверен в правильности своего решения (для сокращения кода геттеры и сеттеры пропущены).

Tourism.java

```
public class Tourism {

    private Tour tour;
 
    public Tourism (Tour tour) {
        this.tour = tour;
    }
 
    public Tour getTour () {
        return tour;
    }
}
```

Tour.java

```
public class Tour {
 
    private Route route;
    private Date beginningDate;
    private Date endDate;
 
    public Tour (Route route, Date beginningDate, Date endDate) {
        this.route = route;
        this.beginningDate = beginningDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
}
```

Route.java

```
public class Route {
 
    private String startPlace;
    private String finishPlace;
 
    private double[] coordinatesOfTheStartPlace;
    private double[] coordinatesOfTheFinishPlace;
 
    private Area area;
 
    public Route (
            String startPlace,
            String finishPlace,
            double[] coordinatesOfTheStartPlace,
            double[] coordinatesOfTheFinishPlace,
            Area area
    ) {
        this.startPlace = startPlace;
        this.finishPlace = finishPlace;
        this.coordinatesOfTheStartPlace = coordinatesOfTheStartPlace;
        this.coordinatesOfTheFinishPlace = coordinatesOfTheFinishPlace;
        this.area = area;
    }
}
```

Area.java

```
public class Area {
 
    private AreaCategory areaCategory;
    private double square;
 
    public Area (AreaCategory areaCategory, double square) {
        this.areaCategory = areaCategory;
        this.square = square;
    }
}
```

AreaCategory.java

```
public class AreaCategory {
 
    private String areaCategory;
 
    public AreaCategory (String areaCategory) {
        this.areaCategory = areaCategory;
    }
}
```

Мое решение правильное? Если нет, подскажите как лучше сделать.
Спасибо

Comment: ИМХО в целом все правильно и понятно. Кроме одного. Не могу понять в чем смысл класса Tourism. Зачем этот класс-обертка вокруг Tour? В чем смысл этой сущности? Что она репрезентует?

Comment: Я начал использовать его для хранения списка походов

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Туризм - это набор походов и набор маршрутов.
- Каждый поход может состоять из одного и более предопределенных маршрутов.
- Маршрут содержит набор участков
- Каждый участок имеет какую-то категорию
- Категория - это обычный энумератор

---

- Атрибуты похода

  - диапазон дат
  - Список маршрутов
- Атрибуты маршрута:

  - Название
  - Общая категория
  - Список участков
- Атрибуты участка

  - Название
  - Категория
  - Набор точек и/или описание